# remotely running the "show()" command on matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: user-interface, ssh, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently trying to run a python script whose end goal is to show a figure. It skeletally looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

p.figure()

[build figure, create plots]

p.show()
```

I'm trying to run this script remotely. It's located on another machine, and I'm trying to run it while ssh'd from my laptop, using:

```
$ ssh -X 'myusername'@'myhostname'
```

However, whenever I execute my script, I get the following error, raised by `p.show()`:

```
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with 'pythonw', not 'python', and only when you are logged 
in on the main display of your Mac.
```

When I run with pythonw instead of python, I get the same error. Is there any way to configure `matplotlib` and `ssh` to be able to show or save plot files on remote machines?

Comment: You will certainly be able to save the figure by calling `py.savefig("filename") instead of `.show()`. I tried to recreate the issue but provided I ssh'd with the `-X` option I did not experience the same issue (Ubuntu 13.01).

Comment: Strangely enough, the .savefig() command produces the exact same error.

Comment: Sorry danig, this appears to be beyond me then!

Comment: have [a look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93340/how-to-open-the-display-from-ssh-login) or [here (for Mac)](http://blog.djmnet.org/2009/05/11/macos-remote-desktop-over-the-internet-using-ssh-secure-shell/), maybe it will help you...